# UNION issue in select sub-query

Tags: mysql

In the below code, how do I combine MRR_Created with MRR_Destroyed in a UNION so it only shows the next number? Right now the query is correct but I don't need to see the increase/decrease separately.

```
 select account.email, account.vip, datediff(now(), account.date_created) AS Age,
(select sum(account_subscription.next_invoice_price) as ActiveMRR
from account_subscription
where account_subscription.status = 'active'
and account_subscription.acctid = account.acctid
) as MRR,
(select count(account_subscription.subid) as Churn
from account_subscription
where account_subscription.date_created between DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2880 MINUTE) and NOW()
and account_subscription.date_closed between DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2880 MINUTE) and NOW()
and account_subscription.acctid = account.acctid
) as Churn,

(select sum(account_subscription.next_invoice_price) as MRR
from account_subscription
where date(account_subscription.date_created) = date(curdate())
and account_subscription.acctid = account.acctid
) as MRR_Created,
(select sum(account_subscription.next_invoice_price) as MRR
from account_subscription
where date(account_subscription.date_closed) = date(curdate())
and account_subscription.acctid = account.acctid
) as MRR_Destroyed,

 concat("https://sitetest.com?ACCTID=",account.acctid) as URL

 from account
 where account.status = 'active'
 and (
account.type in ('affiliate', 'customer', 'customer_freetrial', 'customer_duplicate', 'customer_match')
or account.type is null
)
 group by account.acctid
 order by MRR desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you really need a UNION here. Try replacing

```
(select sum(account_subscription.next_invoice_price) as MRR
from account_subscription
where date(account_subscription.date_created) = date(curdate())
and account_subscription.acctid = account.acctid
) as MRR_Created,
(select sum(account_subscription.next_invoice_price) as MRR
from account_subscription
where date(account_subscription.date_closed) = date(curdate())
and account_subscription.acctid = account.acctid
) as MRR_Destroyed,
```

with

```
(select sum(account_subscription.next_invoice_price) as MRR
from account_subscription
where (date(account_subscription.date_created) = date(curdate())
or date(account_subscription.date_closed) = date(curdate()))
and account_subscription.acctid = account.acctid
) as MRR_Created,
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Almost - the only quirk is that I'm trying to represent total created as a positive number, total closed as a negative and then summing to get the net change. That was the thought behind having two queries and attempting to use UNION

Comment: @skyrunner If the values are stored as you described (opened as positive and closed as negative), this query will give you the net. Or do you mean all values are stored as positive numbers and you need to make that separation within the query?

Comment: Everything is stored as positive, unfortunately

Comment: @skyrunner In this case I'd suggest to add a CASE. Something like this should do: `select sum(case when date(account_subscription.date_closed) = date(curdate()) then -account_subscription.next_invoice_price else account_subscription.next_invoice_price end)` The idea is to use date_closed field as an indicator that this account is closed and add this amount as negative, otherwise keep it positive.